# Can't deploy Adobe AIR to iOS Device

Tags: ios, deployment, air

How can I deploy AIR app to iOS device? I try to export cert + profile from keychain but always see error "Invalid input".
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your app ID is the same reverse domain used in your certificate.

It should NOT include air.

Something like com.domain.appname

Comment: Maybe cert is wrong? How can I get it right? In `iOS App IDs` from developer dashboard there are the same `com.company.air.extension`id.

Comment: It's impossible for someone to resolve this for you. If this is your first app my advise would be to delete all certificates and profiles and start again.

Comment: I made new:
* cert
* app id
* provision profile

Stil invalid input.

Comment: Do you want to post your app-descriptor xml so we can see what you have?

Comment: I found that the problem is in my ANE plugin.

Comment: When I remove iPhone section from plugin -- it compiles. But I need iOS plugin too.